# From a click event on a table cell get selector for row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a td in a table that is created thusly:

I have a click handler on this and when it's clicked I need to do something to another td on this row. In the event handler I can get the id of the td with `e.target.id` but from that I have not figured out how to get the selector for the tr so I can get at the other td.

```js
tr = document.createElement('tr');
input = document.createElement('select');
input.setAttribute('id', 'new=#=' + fld[0] + '=@=' + NEW_ROWS);
.
.
.

div = document.createElement('div');
td = document.createElement('td');
div.appendChild(input)
td.appendChild(div);
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a selector, just use DOM navigation functions.

```
var row = e.target.closest("tr");
```

will return the `<tr>`, and then you can use `row.querySelector("...")` to select something within that row.

Comment: There is a jQuery tag too which will work in IE by the way

Comment: @mplungjan Didn't notice that, just saw that he was using plain JS in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate from the tbody

```
$("tbody").on("click","td",function() {
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  const $cell = $row.find("td").eq(2); // or whatever cell you need
  // do something with cell
})
```